# Executar função ao fechar aba javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Opa,
Preciso executar um ajax ao fechar a aba, é possível?
Tentei:

```
        window.onbeforeunload = ConfirmExit;
        function ConfirmExit()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:'salvar.php',
                data:{usuario:1, ajaxget:true},
                method:'post',
                success:function(data)
                {
                }
            });
            return "Mensagem de fechamento de janela....";
        }
```

Não funciona, se eu retiro o ajax, a mensagem é exibida normalmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você executar um método ajax na saída da aba, o servidor receberá a requisição e a processará, mas não haverá aba para atender a resposta ajax quando a resposta chegar.

Não existe forma de se dar o alerta da resposta do ajax em outra aba, pois isso abriria várias falhas de segurança em potencial em qualquer navegador.

Se você precisa alertar o usuário para algo após ele parar de usar o seu sistema, talvez uma página na internet não seja a melhor forma ser atender os seus usuários.

Pra terminar: não tente segurar a aba do navegador aberta até chegar a resposta do Ajax. Os navegadores podem ver isso como um ataque e fechar a sua aba de qualquer jeito. E o usuário pode fechar uma aba a força também, basta encerrar o processo dela. Não precisa ser um usuário avançado para saber como fazer isso.